# Parse FTP XML Directory add to collection

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net

I retrieve a remote FTP structure in XML format. I'm trying to parse the XML and add each item to a collection like,

```
TestDir/kernel.dll
TestDir/New folder/
TestDir/New folder/mycert.avi
TestDir/New folder/asdasd
TestDir/New folder/asdasd/asdasd
TestDir/New folder/asdasd/asdasd/asdasdasdasd
TestDir/New folder/asdasd/asdasd/asdasdasdasd/done
TestDir/I7Folder/
TestDir/I7Folder/sdfsdfg.txt
TestDir/I7Folder/sdfsdfsdf.txt
```

Here is my XML data,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<dirTree>
    <dir name="TestDir">
        <file sz="364" dt="Tue, 30 Dec 2014 22:56:00 -0500">kernel.dll</file>
        <dir name="New folder">
            <file sz="309" dt="Tue, 30 Dec 2014 23:00:00 -0500">mycert.avi</file>
                <dir name="asdasd">
                    <dir name="asdasd" />
                    <dir name="asdasdasdasd">
                        <dir name="done" />
                    </dir>
                </dir>
            </dir>
        </dir>
        <dir name="I7Folder">
            <file sz="289" dt="Tue, 30 Dec 2014 22:57:00 -0500">sdfsdfg.txt</file>
            <file sz="280" dt="Tue, 30 Dec 2014 22:57:00 -0500">sdfsdfsdf.txt</file>
        </dir>
        <dir name="data">
            <file sz="4727" dt="Tue, 30 Dec 2014 22:56:00 -0500">dasdasd.txt</file>
            <file sz="78419" dt="Tue, 30 Dec 2014 22:56:00 -0500">asdasdas.txt</file>
            <dir name="New folder">
                <dir name="New folder" />
                <dir name="New folder (2)">
                    <dir name="New folder" />
                </dir>
            </dir>
            <dir name="images" />
        </dir>
    </dir>
</dirTree>
```

My code below produces the incorrect output where it would produce something like,

```
TestDir/New folder/New folder/asdasd/asdasd/asdasdasdasd/done/I7Folder/sdfsdfsdf.txt
```

How can I perform the loop so that it doesn't continue using folder names that don't pertain to the correct location. I think it's a simple problem but I can't seem to wrap my head around it as I've been looking at it for to long.

```
Dim doc As New XmlDocument
doc.LoadXml(strXml)

Dim x As XmlNode
For Each x In doc("dirTree").ChildNodes
    Dim strDir As String = ""

    Select Case x.Name
        Case "file"
            colCurrentFiles.Add(x.InnerText)
        Case "dir"
            strDir = x.Attributes(0).Value
            colCurrentFolders.Add(strDir)
            LoopDirectory(x, "", colCurrentFiles, colCurrentFolders, strDir)
            Exit Sub
    End Select
Next
```

```
Private Sub LoopDirectory(x As XmlNode, strDir As String, colCurrentFiles As Collection, colCurrentFolders As Collection, strParentDirectory As String)
    Debug.Write(strDir & vbNewLine)
    Dim y As XmlNode

    For Each y In x.ChildNodes
        Select Case y.Name
            Case "file"
                colCurrentFiles.Add(strDir & "\" & y.InnerText)
            Case "dir"
                If strDir = "" Then
                    strDir = strParentDirectory & "\" & y.Attributes(0).Value
                Else
                    strDir = strDir & "\" & y.Attributes(0).Value
                End If

                Debug.Write(strDir & vbNewLine)
                colCurrentFolders.Add(strDir)

                LoopDirectory(y, strDir, colCurrentFiles, colCurrentFolders, strParentDirectory)
        End Select
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using LINQ to XML instead of old `XmlDocument` API?

```
Sub Main()
    Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load("Input.xml")

    Dim items As List(Of String) = LoopDirectory(doc.Root, "").ToList()

    For Each item In items
        Console.WriteLine(item)
    Next
End Sub

Private Function LoopDirectory(dir As XElement, path As String) As IEnumerable(Of String)
    Dim collection As New List(Of String)

    For Each element In dir.Elements
        If element.Name.LocalName = "file" Then
            collection.Add(String.Format("{0}\{1}", path, CStr(element)))
        Else
            Dim newPath = String.Format("{0}\{1}", path, CStr(element.Attribute("name")))
            collection.Add(newPath)
            collection.AddRange(LoopDirectory(element, newPath))
        End If
    Next

    Return collection
End Function
```

Prints

```
\TestDir
\TestDir\kernel.dll
\TestDir\New folder
\TestDir\New folder\mycert.avi
\TestDir\New folder\asdasd
\TestDir\New folder\asdasd\asdasd
\TestDir\New folder\asdasd\asdasdasdasd
\TestDir\New folder\asdasd\asdasdasdasd\done
\TestDir\I7Folder
\TestDir\I7Folder\sdfsdfg.txt
\TestDir\I7Folder\sdfsdfsdf.txt
\TestDir\data
\TestDir\data\dasdasd.txt
\TestDir\data\asdasdas.txt
\TestDir\data\New folder
\TestDir\data\New folder\New folder
\TestDir\data\New folder\New folder (2)
\TestDir\data\New folder\New folder (2)\New folder
\TestDir\data\images
```